# how to automatically generate mypy stubs using pyproject.toml

Tags: python, python-3.x, mypy, pyproject.toml

i have a package and in it i use `pyproject.toml`
and for proper typing i need stubs generated, although
its kinda annoying to generate them manually every time,
so, is there a way to do it automatically using it ?

i just want it to run stubgen and thats it, just so
`mypy` sees the stubs and its annoying seeing linters
throw warnings and you keep having to `# type: ignore`

heres what i have as of now, i rarely do this so its probably
not that good :

```ini
[build-system]
requires = ["setuptools", "setuptools-scm"]
build-backend = "setuptools.build_meta"

[project]
name = "<...>"
authors = [
    {name = "<...>", email = "<...>"},
]
description = "<...>"
readme = "README"
requires-python = ">=3.10"
keywords = ["<...>"]
license = {text = "GNU General Public License v3 or later (GPLv3+)"}
classifiers = [
    "License :: OSI Approved :: GNU General Public License v3 or later (GPLv3+)",
    "Programming Language :: Python :: 3",
]
dependencies = [
    "<...>",
]
dynamic = ["version"]


[tool.setuptools]
include-package-data = true

[tool.setuptools.package-data]
<...> = ["*.pyi"]

[tool.pyright]
pythonVersion = "3.10"
exclude = [
    "venv",
    "**/node_modules",
    "**/__pycache__",
    ".git"
]
include = ["src", "scripts"]
venv = "venv"
stubPath = "src/stubs"
typeCheckingMode = "strict"
useLibraryCodeForTypes = true
reportMissingTypeStubs = true

[tool.mypy]
exclude = [
    "^venv/.*",
    "^node_modules/.*",
    "^__pycache__/.*",
]
```

thanks for the answers in advance

Comment: i asked the openai ai, it said it isnt possible, although im still not sure, people are smarter anyways, maybe theres *at least* a workaround

Comment: Why do you want to do it with `pyproject.toml`? Can you configure your editor or IDE to automatically run stubgen when a file is changed?

Comment: @Wombatz im not comfortable with depending on a text editor this much, i just made a shellscript to do it, but itd be nice if it was ran on install, ik theres a way to do it but ijdk what to do rn, its solved but nobody have an answer so eh

Answer (score 0):

just make a shellscript and add it to pyproject.toml as a script
:+1: